# Automatic login with oauth2

Tags: ios, oauth, instagram

I'm new to oauth, so please forgive me if this question represents a fundamental misunderstanding about the way the protocol is supposed to work.

I'm tasked with modifying an iOS application to display photos from a particular user's Instagram feed. From reading the Instagram API documentation and playing around some with their Apigee service, it appears that I am required to login via oauth before pulling down the data I need.

In my application, I don't want to force a user to login with their own Instagram credentials in order to access the photo feed. Instead, I want the application to automatically present stored credentials to Instagram and transparently perform the oauth authentication before retrieving the list of photos for display for a user.

Is this possible to implement or is there some requirement in oauth that the user *must* visit the authentication page of a remote service to present credentials by hand?

It seems like I ought to be able to simply store (read: hardcode) and pass the necessary credentials to Instagram without forcing the user to a login page but I haven't been able to find cases where developers have done so.

My questions are: a) Is this possible. b) Is this a good idea? and c) Where might I be able to find more information about doing this? (i.e., is there an iOS oauth library that supports this behavior.

Thanks as always.

Answer (score 2):

if they are true instagram users, you shouldn't do that. You run the risk that Instagram will revoke your app. That's the whole point of Oauth: users don't have and should never have to share their credentials with 3rd party applications.

Now if these users are more like "virtual" users and you are nearly in a 2-legged scenario (i.e. you own the credentials of these users), nothing prevents you to orchestrate the login yourself, instead of displaying a UIWebView and have the user login.

Comment: Yes, agreed on both counts. I'm in the 2-legged scenario you describe. A better way to phrase this question is to ask whether there are any projects or libraries which can assist me in orchestrating the login myself behind the scenes.